# Show that the sequence $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{e^k}{k\log(k+1)}$ is convergent in $c_0$,but not absolutely convergent in $c_0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $x_N = \sum_{n=1}^N $${e^k}\over { k\log(k+1)}$ since $\log(1+k)\le k$
, then we see that $\|x_N\| \le 1$

This question appears in a functional analysis paper but the function does not depend on $x$ so can i use elementary calculus methods to solve this question.

Comment: I do not understand this question.  $x_N$, as you have defined it, is a real number an not a vector in $c_0$.  Perhaps you mean to ask if $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{e^k}{k\log(k+1)}=0$.  This is false, due to $\frac{d}{dk}\frac{e^k}{k\log(k+1)}=\frac{ke^k\log(k+1)-\log(k+1)-\frac{k}{k+1}}{(k\log(k+1))^2}$.

Comment: Is $e^k=\exp(k)$ or do you mean perhaps the sequence $e^k=(\delta_{n,k})_{n\in\mathbb N}$?

Comment: in the question $e^k$ is written in this form $e^{(k)}$,i suppose this means $e^{k}=(\delta_{n,k})$